# Exporting map to TIF with embedded georeference/World using QGIS

Tags: pyqgis, export, georeferencing, api

The Map export from the **Project** menu supports export to TIFF with the World file embedded. The **Print Layout** supports TIFF export with a separate World file. I need the embedded version.

For automation, what is the API function to replicate: ***Project -> Import/Export -> Export Map to Image***?

I have been unable to find it. There are related answers in the forum, but they deal with separate World files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you select `Layout / Export as Image` from the layout screen, after you enter the filename you should get a window where you can choose whether to generate a world file.

[image: Image export options]

If you unselect "Generate world file", I have just verified that the georeferencing (world) information is embedded (at least on 3.16.3 under Windows). You can check yourself by opening a terminal window from the QGIS browser and entering the command `gdalinfo putfilenamehere.tif`.

If you use `Layout / Print` instead, and somehow generate a TIF file as output, then you are using some sort of installed system TIF file driver, most often installed with fax software. Such a driver will write normal TIFs, not GeoTiffs, and no world information will be embedded.

Comment: To add to this, I've found ticking Crop to Content to be quite critical, otherwise the georeferencing seems to come out wrong (3.30.2)